# End \DeclareCaptionFormat and revert to default caption settings

Tags: captions

I have defined my own caption format for the algorithmic floats, which is working quite fine:

```latex
\DeclareCaptionFormat{algor}{%
  \hrulefill\par\offinterlineskip\vskip1pt%
  \textbf{#1#2}#3\offinterlineskip\hrulefill}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{algori}{singlelinecheck=off,format=algor,labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{style=algori}
```

However, I want the figures in my document to have the default caption settings. Please suggest how I can make that happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you define your own caption style via:

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{<formatname>}{<code for format>}
```

and then use this format for a particular float environment as:

```
\captionsetup[<float_environment>]{singlelinecheck=off, labelsep=colon,format=<formatname>}
```

Here labelsep is set as 'colon', which can also be altered to 'space' etc.

This caption formatting can be used in the following manner for the given problem

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{algor}{%
  \hrulefill\par\offinterlineskip\vskip1pt%
  \textbf{#1#2}#3\offinterlineskip\hrulefill}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{algori}{singlelinecheck=off,format=algor,labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{style=algori}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{figur}{%
  \begin{center}
  \textbf{#1#2}#3
  \end{center}}
\captionsetup[figure]{singlelinecheck=off,format=figur,labelsep=colon}
```